# Exposing properties of an object contained by a control

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have a simple object, could be a struct even, with three properties that I want to expose to the designer. Basically, I want my property to look like the Size or Padding properties of your average control, with an arrow to collapse or expand the properties as a sub-list of the control's properties. However, I cannot find any reference as to how this can be done. Since there are several types of properties with this collapse/extend look and feel I imagine there's something built-in I can use. If I have to implement my own Designer or Editor, forget it; it's not worth it. I doubt that that's the case; there's gotta be some simple attribute I can stick on the property or class that tells the designer to expose the browsable sub-properties.

Comment: Forget it, you need a TypeConverter.

Comment: I figured. I looked at the various drawing structs in Object Browser and found that they all have a converter. I just flattened the object structure and moved on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans said, the solution is to implement a custom TypeConverter. Not worth it for me, so I just flattened the object hierarchy and it works well enough for my purposes. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called Attributes.
Or more specifically [Design-Time Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx)

```
[Category("Hello World")]
[Description("Indicates if Button is Enabled or not")]
[Browsable(true)]
public int Blah { get; set; }
```

Comment: Except in my example, Blah is not an int but a MyObject, which contains an int which I want to show on the properties list of a control containing a Blah. Decorating Blah as you have done makes the property visible, but only the name of the object type is shown and nothing is editable about it from the designer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yochai's answer, please note the `Designer` attribute which allows you to set which designer will be used.

By setting the designer type you really have full control on the UI Visual Studio will show for your property.

Comment: OK, but part of the question was whether there was a built-in designer to handle simple objects.

Comment: Possibly, if your class inherits from `Component`, you will get that for free. But I'm not sure I remember right, and can't check right now.